# Alter Table SQLLITE

Tags: sqlite, alter

I want to rename table name from `books_temp` to `books`.

I am getting syntax error when I doing in terminal.

But within Sqlite Browser it is working correctly.

```
alter table books_temp rename to books;
```

> SQL error: near "alter": syntax error

[image: Error Image]

Comment: Is your terminal on a phone?

Comment: It is my terminal on ubuntu